# Can't display ERC-20 tokens in Polygon

Tags: gnosis-safe

My friend has sent me some ERC-20 tokens but he sent them to my Gnosis-SAFE address. But my SAFE address was only on the ETHEREUM network while he sent it to Polygon.

I have created a Polygon Safe with the same address but I can't see my ERC-20 tokens on Gnosis UI and safe-cli balances command. (https://github.com/gnosis/safe-cli)

Why I can't see my tokens and how to access my ERC-20 tokens to transfer them to another address.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you share the address of the Safe? when you recreate the Safe on polygon it will use a master copy that is not supported by the indexing services on polygon. The safe-cli and the interface rely on these indexing services. The you will have to check the balance on a blockexplorer.

Comment: That means the UI and command line are just not visible balance of tokens  but I can still transfer tokens through the command line interface

Comment: Yes, that should be the case

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But when  I reproduce this case on my test Safe, It still shows my fake token in UI and CLI. :(  https://polygonscan.com/address/0xb5adBe76609C6497326340bD13d4c98CD957F07d#tokentxns

Comment: How do you transfer the token for this one